# How can I use javascript in TWebBrowser in Delphi XE5 on all platforms (IOS,WIN,ANDROID)?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, twebbrowser, delphi-xe5

I want to use `TWebBrowser` on Android in Delphi XE5 to connect to google maps api. 
I wrote my own component which works on WIN platform. I used `Twebbrowser` and `IHTMLDocument2`.
For example :

```
if Self.Document as IHTMLDocument2<>nil then
  with TWebBrowser(Self).Document as IHTMLDocument2 do
    with ParentWindow do
      execScript(aScript, 'JavaScript');
```

Is Any chance to run something similar in `TWebbrowser` on Android (execute javaScript in `TWebBrowser`)?

Is any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) of the Android `WebView`, which I currently assume (without having resource to the source) to be behind `TWebBrowser`, you'd need to pull out the underlying Android `WebView` and call its add `JavascriptInterface()` method ([documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)).

Whether anyone's already done that, I don't know. But that looks to be the requirement. The next step is working out how to access the underlying `WebView`. I'd imagine that is tucked away in the Android implementation unit for the web browser, so that will be tricky, and may require you to modify the source files.

Anyway, hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I thought about it but it is  solution only for ANDROID but TWebBrowser works on all platforms. Maybe embded webbrowser like chromium, but I Don't know if it works on other platforms than WIN. Maybe you know answer ??

Comment: The question was tagged for Android, so I gave an Android-oriented answer, indeed. I'm not sure you'd readily get a cross-platform solution without some level of abstraction over separate implementations, much like `TWebBrowser` already employs in its implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will try chromium if will not work i will take your direction.

Comment: I found that Delphi has Androidapi.JNI.WebKit but can someone help me how to create and show the browser in my fmx window ? Please give me some direction.... Thank you

Comment: Ok.I found direction and solutuion. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, perhaps you can outline how you solved it in case someone in the future would Google here. He'd be helped with your road marks more than just " it is possible". Stack Overflow aims at being the ultimate documentation for everything,  so the more of solution the question has - the better it gets

Answer (score 0):

I propose to You to use something like:

```
 TWebBrowser.Document AS IHTMLDocument2
```

and then check OnKeyDown event what is the caption of all inputs objects in DOM.

Hope it helps... I'm not the God of XE5 :-)

Comment: Here is good tutorial about working with website forms :)
http://delphi.about.com/od/twebbrowser/a/submit_web_form.htm

Answer (score 0):

I saw an example that wrote the static html to a local file, then loaded the local file.

WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://MyFile.html')

If you find a solution that works in iOS and Android, I'd love to hear about it.

Struggling with the same issue right now.